# history.push() using react-router-dom works in some components but not others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

So as the title says. I'm using React-router-dom and so within my App.js file i have my Router set up containing a Switch and multiple Routes. From a couple of smaller components i have no problem using useHisory and history.push() to manipulate the history and navigate my app.

However within my App.js file it doesn't work and i get returned:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

I'm at a loss as to what is the problem and any help would be much appriciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  useHistory,
} from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

import unsplash from "../api/unsplash";
import Header from "./Header";
import Customise from "./Customise";
import LandingPage from "./LandingPage";
import GameBoard from "./GameBoard";
import GameFinished from "./GameFinished";

function App() {
  const [searchImageTerm, setSearchImageTerm] = useState("south africa");
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [randomisedImages, setRandomisedImages] = useState([]);

  const [roundStarted, setRoundStarted] = useState(false);
  const [firstSelectedTile, setFirstSelectedTile] = useState(null);
  const [secondSelectedTile, setSecondSelectedTile] = useState(null);
  const [matchedTiles, setMatchedTiles] = useState([]);
  const [endOfTurn, setEndOfTurn] = useState(false);

  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(2);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [difficulty, setDifficulty] = useState(8);

  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    getImages();
  }, [searchImageTerm, difficulty]);

  useEffect(() => {
    randomiseImagesWithID(images);
  }, [images]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
      finishGame();
    }
  }, [seconds, minutes]);

  const finishGame = () => {
    history.push(`/gamefinished`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (roundStarted) {
      let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
        if (seconds > 0) {
          setSeconds(seconds - 1);
        }
        if (seconds === 0) {
          if (minutes === 0) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
          } else {
            setMinutes(minutes - 1);
            setSeconds(59);
          }
        }
      }, 1000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
      };
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (matchedTiles.length > 0 && matchedTiles.length === images.length / 2) {
      alert("YOU WON!");
    }
  }, [matchedTiles]);

  const getImages = async () => {
    const response = await unsplash.get("/search/photos", {
      params: { query: searchImageTerm, per_page: difficulty },
    });
    setImages(response.data.results);
  };

  const generateTileId = () => {
    return "tile_id_" + Math.random().toString().substr(2, 8);
  };

  const randomiseImagesWithID = (images) => {
    let duplicateImagesArray = [...images, ...images];
    var m = duplicateImagesArray.length,
      t,
      i;
    while (m) {
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
      t = duplicateImagesArray[m];
      duplicateImagesArray[m] = duplicateImagesArray[i];
      duplicateImagesArray[i] = t;
    }

    let finalArray = [];
    for (let image of duplicateImagesArray) {
      finalArray.push({
        ...image,
        tileId: generateTileId(),
      });
    }
    setRandomisedImages([...finalArray]);
  };

  const startRound = () => {
    setRoundStarted(true);
  };

  const onTileClick = (tileId, id) => {
    // is the tile already paired && is the tile selected && is it the end of the turn?
    if (
      !matchedTiles.includes(id) &&
      tileId !== firstSelectedTile &&
      !endOfTurn
    ) {
      // find image id for first selcted id for comparrison
      const firstSelctedTileId = randomisedImages.find(
        (image) => image.tileId === firstSelectedTile
      )?.id;
      // if there is no selected tile set first selected tile
      if (!firstSelectedTile) {
        setFirstSelectedTile(tileId);
      } else {
        // if the second tile matches the first tile set matched tiles to include
        if (id === firstSelctedTileId) {
          setMatchedTiles([...matchedTiles, id]);
          // add points to score
          setScore(score + 6);
          // reset selected tiles
          setFirstSelectedTile(null);
        } else {
          // deduct points from score
          setScore(score - 2);
          // set and display second tile choice
          setSecondSelectedTile(tileId);
          // set end of turn so tiles cannot be continued to be selected
          setEndOfTurn(true);
          // reset all values after a few seconds
          setTimeout(() => {
            setFirstSelectedTile(null);
            setSecondSelectedTile(null);
            setEndOfTurn(false);
          }, 1500);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const onResetClick = () => {
    randomiseImagesWithID(images);
    setFirstSelectedTile(null);
    setSecondSelectedTile(null);
    setMatchedTiles([]);
    setScore(0);
    setEndOfTurn(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Container>
          <Header
            onResetClick={onResetClick}
            score={score}
            seconds={seconds}
            minutes={minutes}
          />
          <Main>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/gameboard">
                <GameBoard
                  images={randomisedImages}
                  onTileClick={onTileClick}
                  firstSelectedTile={firstSelectedTile}
                  secondSelectedTile={secondSelectedTile}
                  matchedTiles={matchedTiles}
                />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/customise">
                <Customise
                  setSearchImageTerm={setSearchImageTerm}
                  setDifficulty={setDifficulty}
                  setMinutes={setMinutes}
                  startRound={startRound}
                />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/gamefinished">
                <GameFinished />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/">
                <LandingPage startRound={startRound} />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </Main>
        </Container>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 7rem;
`;

const Main = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
`;
```

And to give an example of where my code is working as expected:

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

function LandingPage({ startRound }) {
  const history = useHistory();

  const startGame = () => {
    history.push(`/gameboard`);
    startRound();
  };

  const customiseGame = () => {
    history.push("/customise");
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <WelcomeText>
        <p>Match the tiles by picking two at a time.</p>
        <p>Gain points for a correct match but lose points if they dont.</p>
        <p>Good Luck!</p>
      </WelcomeText>
      <ButtonContainer>
        <GameButton onClick={() => startGame()}>Start</GameButton>
        <GameButton onClick={() => customiseGame()}>Customise</GameButton>
      </ButtonContainer>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does the url update (and component doesn't render) ? Or url doesn't update at all?

Comment: `useHistory` provides you history object from React Router context and this context will be set as soon as you write "<Router ....". `App` component doesn't have access to this context, so you can't use `useHistory` in App.

Comment: no nothing updates and it goes straight to error page

Comment: Quick solution: Wrap your `App` component in `Router` and remove `Router` from the `App` component.

Comment: So Ajeet you're saying that only components within the Router tags have that context and therefore can reference. hence the error of undefined. Is there a solution to have all my state high up in the app and still be able to use router even if I need to reference the history object?

Comment: Yes. Solution 1: Go to index.jsx file and write `<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>`. Solution 2: Use [Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Router), not `BrowserRouter`. And provide your own `history` object. Benefit: You can now import the `history` you created anywhere and do `.push` on it.

Comment: Is it more common for React aps to actualy use the Router instead of BrowserRouter and create a custom history object? It sounds like an easier solution but documentation suggests that normally high level routers are used instead. Does it become less of an issue once you are using redux across the components as the state isn't living high in the app and each component will be calling state values and  calls to history will be from within the router more likely then?

Comment: Using `BrowserRouter` is more common. But there are no cons of using `Router`. I have been using `Router` because sometimes I need to access `history` in a file which is not a React component. Yes, First, I was about to ask why you have so many state vars in `App` component. So, yes, mostly we don't need "history" object in `App` (root) component.

Comment: The correct answer is in the second comment: you can use `useHistory` hook only in the component which is wrapped by `Router`. Split your App component into several components and implement correct wrapping.

Comment: Thats great to know. Haha yeah I'm still getting to grips with Redux. I'm nearly confident with vanilla redux but still need to seek out the documentation around redux with hooks. But that is something I want to come back and do with this app once I'm more familiar with Redux hooks. Thanks for all your help I think I have a much better understanding than If someone had simply provided an answer and as as someone self teaching thats so valuable! Have a great day.

Comment: See Redux Toolkit - https://redux-toolkit.js.org/ for redux.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` is because you have initialized/assigned history before render has returned (hence the router never populated.

```
const history = useHistory();
```

Change it to this and everything should be working as expected (Warning: I haven't tested it myself):

```
const finishGame = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    history.push(`/gamefinished`);
  };
```

It will work because `finishGame` is only called inside `useEffect` which is called after the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with your code. Try this

```
npm uninstall react-router-dom && npm i react-router-dom
```

Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass history prop one component to another component.

like

```
// First component

import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const firstComponent = () => {
const history = useHistory();

return (
<SecondComponent history=history />
)
}

const SecondComponent = ({history}) => (
....
);
```